# influxDB - Get daily Max. value

Tags: influxdb

I have data with hydrological measurements.

I want to get the daily max Water flow:

```
from(bucket: "API")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "hydro")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "temperature")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["loc"] == "XXX")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: max, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "max")
```

For some reason, for some days, this returns multiple measurements per day.
But not always.

How do I get only the max entry per day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `every` parameter in the `aggregateWindow` method to `1d`:

```
from(bucket: "API")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "hydro")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "temperature")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["loc"] == "XXX")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: max, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "max")
```

See [the Flux documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/aggregatewindow/#every) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. This works. You must be a very good programmer!